# group by is not working in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I want group my data by createdAt but it is not working I don't know why...
Only group by id which is useless for me.

This is working:

```
SELECT "id", "createdAt", "updatedAt" 
FROM "tables" AS "Table" 
WHERE "Table"."createdAt" 
BETWEEN '2014-04-21 20:46:25.938-04' AND '2015-04-21 20:46:25.938-04'
GROUP BY "id";
```

This is what I want but it is not working at all ...

```
SELECT "createdAt", "updatedAt" 
FROM "tables" AS "Table" 
WHERE "Table"."createdAt" 
BETWEEN '2014-04-21 20:46:25.938-04' AND '2015-04-21 20:46:25.938-04' 
GROUP BY "createdAt";
```

I have error:

> ERROR:  column "Table.updatedAt" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or
>   be used in an aggregate function

Comment: `group by` is working just fine in Postgres. You are usage is invalid. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+must+appear+in+the+GROUP+BY+clause+

Comment: Please, [don't use `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  The use here is identical to an `=`, although you haven't specified the full precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID is unique and `group by ID` works just like a plain select.

Column `createdAt` is not unique and results with same `createdAt` value must be grouped. You should provide a way how they will be grouped - use aggreagete function, remove them from `select` clause or add them to `group by` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can only select aggregate functions or the fields which listed in "GROUP BY" as in told

```
ERROR: column "Table.updatedAt" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Your first query only works because "id" is your primary key therefore it is guaranteed that each group will have only one row.